# Pull Request warning in Azure Repos

Tags: git, azure-repos

I have created a PR, no merge conflict displayed. In Azure Repos a warning is displayed:
Warning: Multiple merge bases detected. The list of commits displayed might be incomplete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Warning%3A+Multiple+merge+bases+detected.+The+list+of+commits+displayed+might+be+incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Pull master and merge=> the warning will disappear.
for more info on this issue see:
[Warning: Multiple merge bases detected. The list of commits displayed might be incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211632/warning-multiple-merge-bases-detected-the-list-of-commits-displayed-might-be-i)