# Azure DevOps shows old file version in PR

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

One of the guys in our team created a Pull Request and gets the message "Warning: Multiple merge bases detected. The list of commits displayed might be incomplete or excessive."

Not sure why this is but we can live with it, but in the code windows the source file (left) is not the current version, when compared with the latest in the repository.

His branch is quite old so he merged develop into it to try to resolve the issue, but this is still the same.

Even more strangely, if he clicks the "swap" button to switch the branches, i.e. merge from develop into his feature, the develop version shown (now right) is the correct one.
Clicking it again shows the incorrect version on the left again.

Other people have pulled his branch down and tried to create a PR to see if the same happens - the results are the same.

We think this will be fine to merge it as we can always roll it back, but what could be causing this?

Comment: Does this answer answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72123521/717372

Comment: It might explain the warning (but I don't think so), however it definitely doesn't explain the incorrect file version being displayed.

Comment: On the three dots menu, choose View Merge Commit. That will show you what the actual changes will be at the time it was last calculated. If the target branch is out of date since the last push for that PR, there is also another option to recalculate the merge commit.