# How to avoid, how to resolve the Azure Dev Ops pull request warning about multiple merge bases detected?

Tags: git, azure-devops

How to avoid?, how to resolve the Azure Dev Ops pull request warning about multiple merge bases detected?

Warning: Multiple merge bases detected. The list of commits displayed might be incomplete or excessive. Use View merge changes to see the result of merging this pull request.

Microsoft says:
"To get rid of the multiple merge bases warning, tie the branches to a single common ancestor by either rebasing your branch on target, or merging target into your branch. Those actions get rid of the warning message and help you check if the actual changes are fine"

I'm not entirely sure what this means and I also get the same warning in trying to rebase the branch. I will try to do some research ..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops

Comment: Discussion here:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211632/warning-multiple-merge-bases-detected-the-list-of-commits-displayed-might-be-i
This is a duplicate